# Key '@' (Keycode 49) and key '<' (keycode 94) are inverted on macbookPro keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro, xkb

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 on a MacbookPro and keys 49 and 94 are inverted... I resolved this problem with `xmodmap`, but this won't apply permanently. After some research I found `xmodmap` is no longuer use by Ubuntu but `xkb` instead. So I searched in the configuration of xkb and I found in the config file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/macintosh` this lines :

```
xkb_keycodes "badmap" {
    <TLDE> =  94;
    <LSGT> =  49;
};

xkb_keycodes "goodmap" {
    <TLDE> =  49;
    <LSGT> =  94;
};
```

This is exactly my problem, this two keys are inverted. So I wondering if I can't change my layout configuration with the param `badmap`.

---

The ouput of `setxkbmap -query -v 10`

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     fr,fr,us
variant:    mac,oss,
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(azerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+fr(mac)+fr(oss):2+us:3+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     fr,fr,us
variant:    mac,oss,
```

Comment: First: Do you know that your keyboard model is set correctly?

Comment: I think the keyboard layout is wrong, because when I switch in a different language layout like French, Swenden, etc I've got the same problem even if I select a no Macintosh layout.

Comment: No, I was talking about the model. Can you please run the command `setxkbmap -query -v 10` and show us the output by editing your question.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I gave this a new try: Wrote a new answer and deleted the old one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled upon [this patch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/xkeyboard-config/wily/view/head:/debian/patches/revert-goodmap-badmap-for-apple.diff), which led me to the solution:

Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and set:

```
XKBOPTIONS="apple:badmap"
```

At next reboot those keys will be switched.

Comment: Big thanks to you ! This is exactly what I am looking for ! This solved my problem. Thank you !

Comment: Big up! Same problem (and solution) with a swiss german mac keyboard. Where < and § where switched!

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Euro Mac English kbd here. (don't ask, bought in a urgent moment when overseas and my keyboard died)