# How do I configure a full size Mac keyboard with Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac

I am a Linux novice so please excuse my ignorance. The first hurdle I have come across is finding the correct keyboard layout!! I am using a 2009 mac pro desktop and none of the keyboard layouts seem to match it within settings (or during initial installation). I tried installing on an old MacBook and the UK Mac keyboard layout appears to fit the MacBook keyboard layout. I read that the full size Mac keyboard support was dropped in favour of the MacBook keyboard layout a few Ubuntu versions back. Can anyone confirm this for me and more specifically offer me a solution to get my keyboard working correctly???
Its really frustrating trying to learn Linux commands when bits of your keyboard either don't do anything or don't do what they should do!!
Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/843590/keycode-49-and-keycode-94-are-inverted-on-macbookpro-keyboard) apply?