# Ubuntu Remapping key issue

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've tried remapping a key thats not on my current keyboard but I cant get it to work on Ubuntu 17.04.

I edited the file

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

The key that I im missing on my keyboard is the below key LSGT (to the right of the <kbd>shift</kbd> key)

```
key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };
```

So I want to replace below section <kbd>§</kbd> key (left of numeric <kbd>1</kbd> key), with the key above. Because I don't ever thing i've used this key

So I run

```
xev -event keyboard
```

to get the key info. But I dont see the key number I should use?

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xdd, subw 0x0, time 18369362, (-451,244), root:(348,296),
    state 0x0, keycode 49 (keysym 0xa7, section), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 a7) "§"
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 a7) "§"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When I was testing this out I had a key just to test with so I took the below key

```
key <AD12> { [ U0328,  dead_circumflex,  dead_tilde,  dead_caron ] };
```

And changed that to.

```
key <AD12> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };
```

And after this I runned the following command to clear the cache

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data

After this I signed out and back in again. 
But the keys stays the same and nothing happends?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible alternative approach to achieve what you want: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843590/key-keycode-49-and-key-keycode-94-are-inverted-on-macbookpro-keyboar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from Gunnars comment I found the answer.

When I viewed

```
/etc/default/keyboard
```

To see my current locale keyboard setting in XKBLAYOUT.

So I got back to.

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

And changed both pc and my locale file that I found in above XKBLAYOUT setting.

From

```
key <LSGT>  { [      less,     greater,         bar,    brokenbar ] };
```

To

```
key <TLDE>  { [      less,     greater,         bar,    brokenbar ] };
```

Did a

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

Singed out and back in and now its working. And the key is remapped.
(Not really sure why I had to change both pc and locale file, I tought pc file would have precedence over the locale file)

Comment: Great that you figured it out. Actually I think that changing `/etc/default/keyboard` as suggested in the answer to the linked question would have been sufficient, though.