# No way to have Dutch(Belgian) [edit:'Belgian'] keyboard layout working on 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, keyboard-layout, input-language, input

After playing with Ubuntu among other flavours of Linux in VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro for several years, I figured it was time to build myself a new computer and use Ubuntu 20.04 as main OS.
While any virtualised Ubuntu environment recognises the Apple keyboard perfectly, the layout of the keyboard hooked to my newly built computer -regular Windows keyboard with Dutch(Belgian) Azerty layout- seems impossible to set up.
No matter what Input Source selected, parentheses among several other keys like the @ always seem to be out of place.   Familiar keyboard layouts available in 16.04 and 18.04 seem to no longer exist.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something.

Comment: As regards the `@` character, I suspect that [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/843590) applies. Besides that you need to be more specific to improve your chances to get help. It's not even clear to me which keyboard layout you are talking about. AFAIK the Dutch layouts are QWERTY.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  While Dutch keyboard layouts are indeed Querty, Dutch(Belgian) keyboard layouts are Azerty because of the French influence I guess.

Comment: To be clear, @ works fine on the Dutch(Belgian) keyboard in Ubuntu VM on the Mac.  The issue is with regard to the newly built computer which has an Azerty hp "Pavilion Wired Keyboard 300" hooked to it.  The computer is custom built and runs Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: There is no "Dutch (Belgian)" layout in Ubuntu 20.04. Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: Could it be Belgian(Dutch) then?  Which is also nowhere to be found unfortunately :-(  
The output of the above command reads as follows:
[('xkb', 'fr+mac'), ('xkb', 'nl+std')]

Furthermore, browsing through the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ directory I stumbled upon the 'be' file which features a nice comment outlining my exact keyboard layout.  I wonder why this layout isn't available while the file exists, does it have a syntax error and therefor ignored?

Comment: If a French locale has been generated on your machine, the Belgian layouts may be found in a sub menu in _Settings_ if you click "French".

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the clarification @GunnarHjalmarsson :-)
It's confusing, Belgium being a multilingual country, during installation I naively looked for "Dutch" Azerty keyboard instead of "French" ^_^'

Comment: It's indeed confusing. GNOME logic. Don't blame me. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. To set AZERTY run `sudo setxkbmap be` in a terminal
2. If the above doesn't set the keyboard properly then try `sudo setxkbmap fr`
3. `sudo loadkeys xx` (xx=be or fr)

Comment: I removed Dutch(belgian) in the GUI. I wanted to add it again but it was not their anymore. `sudo setxkbmap be` did the trick for me. Although it does not work after a restart. Any commands for keeping it in restart?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, unlike in previous editions of Ubuntu, first generate a locale before  eventually finding the input layout in the settings.

Comment: Please feel free to make some noise at [this GNOME issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/82).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I found out that the **Belgian** (azerty) keyboard for the MacBookPro (the **macintosh version**) is available under the name: **Belgian (alt.)**

The default Belgian keyboard is just called: **Belgian**, for both spoken languages Dutch and French.

**Do not look for Dutch** as this is the layout for the Netherlands.

It's a variant of the French keyboard but the special characters are placed different in Belgium and France and also on the mac keyboard.

[keyboard layout for belgian (mac)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5794M.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the input, however as I stated in the OP, "build myself a new computer" meaning non Apple hardware with a regular Azerty keyboard. Since then I realized I was simply overlooking the option ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You should select French(Macintouch)! It worked for me!