# Missing apple keyboard layout: English (International, Macintosh)

Tags: keyboard-layout, apple-keyboard

The "International Keyboard" layout from the apple magic keyboard seems to be missing, there is an international layout for UK, but the plain international layout is not there:

#### English (International, Macintosh) <- missing layout

[image: magic keyboard (international)]
** This is the layout that is missing*

as a reference here are the other macintosh keyboard layouts, whereas the closes keyboard layout is the `English (UK, Macintosh)` but the `shift + 3` combination is incorrect.

#### English (UK, Macintosh)

[image: English (UK, Macintosh)]

- `Shift + 3`: should be `#` but instead is `£`

#### English (Macintosh)

[image: English (Macintosh)]

- The keys left of `Z` should be  `backquote key` and `~`
- The keys left of `1` should be `§` and `±`

#### English (UK,Intl., Macintosh)

[image: English (UK,Intl., Macintosh)]

- Multiple `shift + number` keys are incorrect
- Multiple `super + number` keys are incorrect

Comment: It's not clear to me which layout you are looking for. Did you try _English (Macintosh)_? If that does not satisfy your needs, please be more specific about what you would like to see.

Comment: There are clearly large differences, look at the image I posted, check the key left of the Z key =  ` and ~ 

The key left of 1 = § and ±

Comment: I have added better explanations with image examples, doing this I came to the conclusion that the missing layout is English (International, Macintosh). The closest layout is English (UK, Macintosh), which has noticeably one incorrect key. (merits more investigation into all other keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to make the adjustment suggested in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/844931). Once you have done that, the *English (Macintosh)* keyboard layout probably fits your physical keyboard.

*Edit:*

If editing `/etc/default/keyboard` proved to not be persistent, the explanation might be that there is only one user on your system and that the change was silently wiped out when you added or removed input sources in Settings.

If you set it by running this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['apple:badmap']"
```

instead it ought to stay.

(Looks like you hit a known inconsistency where GNOME and XKB don't play well together. That's a bug, and the issue is mentioned in passing in the discussion at [bug #1892014](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1892014).)

Comment: Thanks that works , though I still think the international layout should be added to the list of keyboards. But anyway thanks 

Comment: After restarting it seems to be back to the old layout, any idea how I can persist this change?

Comment: @PaulvanDyk: Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks that resolves it!

Answer (score 2):

I feel stupid for not figuring this out myself but here's how to get the English (Macintosh) layout back for your keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04 (late 2020 earlier 2021 since it worked fine earlier in 2020).

[1] Open **Settings > Region & Language > Input Sources**

[2] On the right under Input Sources click the + icon

[3] Click the ellipsis

[4] Click your preferred language ...

**UPDATE FEB 2021**

***... at this moment it's important to pay attention as it happens so fast you will miss it. Once you've selected your preferred language the list of languages updates and becomes a list of kb layouts. If you close the modal you'll only get the language, but if you scroll down the list you'll see the mac layout.***

[5] .. *then* select "English (Macintosh)" as your ***preferred layout***

[6] You're done

When 20.04 was initially released we had to *search* for English (Macintosh) after clicking the ellipsis in step [3] above.  It seems that keyboard layout is now grouped *within* the selected keyboard source.

By that I mean after I selected English (Canada) a *new* list appeared from which I could select a keyboard layout *for* English (Canada).

Comment: When I click on the ellipsis I can see more English variants but the Macintosh is not there... I installed all the English language pack. Is there something else that can be done?

Comment: Yes, it looks like Ubuntu has been moving things around in the last few updates.  I'll update my answer above ...

Comment: I'm struggling to find the English Macintosh layout on Ubuntu 21.04. Other languages for the Macintosh layout appear by navigating into the sub-menus.

Comment: I found a workaround by using gsettings to set the layout.
```gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us+mac')]"```