# Macintosh Keyboard — how to switch keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I am on ubuntu 20.04 and I have attached a Logitech Keyboard with Macintosh Layout. Withing settings I was able to add this Layout and viewing it from the Settings yields that image:

[image: German Macintosh layout]

The Keyboard itself does exactly look like the one on the image, but two keys are swapped when pressing them.

These are: `^` and `<`. In other words »caret key and greater key« need to be remapped.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**
Following some tutorial on the web just ran those commands:

```
xmodmap -pk | grep -i greater
…
94      0x003c (less)   0x003e (greater) …
…

xmodmap -pk | grep -i less
…
94      0x003c (less)   0x003e (greater) …
…

xmodmap -pk | grep -i asciicircum
…
15      0x0036 (6)  … 0x005e (asciicircum)
…

xmodmap -pk | grep -i degree
19 …
34 …
49 …
```

So, finding the key with the `^` is somewhat difficult

**Update #2**

1. using `xmodmap -pke` makes it much easier to find the keys
2. finally that fixed the issue:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = dead_circumflex degree dead_circumflex degree U2032 U2033 U2032 U2033 grave asciitilde"
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = less greater less greater bar dead_belowmacron bar dead_belowmacron less greater bar dead_belowmacron"
```

Comment: Run `xev` from a terminal. This will give you a new window. Place your mouse cursor in this window and press the ^ key.

Comment: thanks! Now I now the key codes: 94 and 49

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Key '@' (Keycode 49) and key '<' (keycode 94) are inverted on macbookPro keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843590/key-keycode-49-and-key-keycode-94-are-inverted-on-macbookpro-keyboar)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Well that solution looks pretty nice, gonna give it a shut.

Answer (score 0):

So the command that solves the problem for me is that one:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = dead_circumflex degree dead_circumflex degree U2032 U2033 U2032 U2033 grave asciitilde"
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = less greater less greater bar dead_belowmacron bar dead_belowmacron less greater bar dead_belowmacron"
```

I have put it in a script `~/swap-keys.sh` and each time I am using the apple keyboard, I ran this and it works.