# MX Keys for Mac mixed up a few buttons

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, logitech

I am using the Mx Keys For Mac keyboard on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) and for some reason the keyboard has a few keys "out of order".

When I press the key next to the number one, the keyboard sends a command to press the key next to Shift L.

This problem occurs on a clean new Ubuntu installation.

[keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZThf.png)

How can this be fixed?

Note! The same problem does not exist with MX Keys keyboard (Win/Mac version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a while ago I would have said that your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843590/key-keycode-49-and-key-keycode-94-are-inverted-on-macbookpro-keyboar). But unfortunately the answer to the other question no longer works since the Debian patch which made it possible was dropped.

https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/data/xkeyboard-config/-/commit/c95fcccc

In Ubuntu 22.04 I suppose the easiest way is to edit the applicable keyboard layout file directly. You should find it in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed the problem with your instructions. Here is also the ready-made file to fix this problem https://github.com/vmvartiainen/mx-keys-for-mac-on-linux