# English keyboard layout in Ubuntu that is very close to macOS one but allows Compose key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 at work and macOS at home.
Both computers have internional keyboards.
That means that there is an extra button between left Shift and Z buttons.

However, I have the following problem.
I´d like to using this extra button as it is used in macOS: for entering backtick `` ` `` and `~` characters because I use them extensively in both operating systems.

The problem is that when I choose "English (UK, Macintosh)" keyboard layout in Ubuntu, it does not allow to use Compose key to enter easily characters like ü and ä.
I chose another layout ¨English (UK, Macintosh, intl.)¨ but it has superweird behavior with backticks, tilde, and double quotes as it expects me to enter something directly after that (for example ~n becomes ñ), which makes writing in Markdown or programming code a torture.

Is there a good English keyboard layout in Ubuntu 22.04 that 1) has backtick and tilde between left Shift and Z buttons; 2) Allows Compose button to enter special European characters like ü?

Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer covering 1), but I don't really understand what you mean by 2). Did you see [the docs about compose keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose)?

Answer (score 1):

On the **English (UK, Macintosh)** layout, the backtick and tilde symbols are actually mapped to the key to the left of the Z key.

However...

On some Apple devices, and for some reason, that key is switched with the key to the left of the number 1 key. So I assume that some Apple hardware is involved in your case.

In Ubuntu 20.04 there was a simple way to fix that:

[Key '@' (Keycode 49) and key '<' (keycode 94) are inverted on macbookPro keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843590/key-keycode-49-and-key-keycode-94-are-inverted-on-macbookpro-keyboar/844931)

But that Debian specific feature was [dropped in Ubuntu 22.04](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/data/xkeyboard-config/-/commit/c95fcccc).

One clumsier way to switch the keys back to their intended state is to edit the file in question directly. It's the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` file and this diff shows what can be done:

```
--- gb.orig
+++ gb
@@ -188,8 +188,8 @@
 
     key <AE02> {   [               2,              at,         EuroSign    ]   };
     key <AE03> {   [               3,        sterling,       numbersign    ]   };
-    key <TLDE> {   [         section,       plusminus ]    };
-    key <LSGT> {   [           grave,      asciitilde ]    };
+    key <LSGT> {   [         section,       plusminus ]    };
+    key <TLDE> {   [           grave,      asciitilde ]    };
 
     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
     include "level3(enter_switch)"
```

Comment: yes, I tried to use the English (UK, Macintosh). However, as I said before, the Compose key stops working. This key allows to enter key sequences that are transformed to additional characters, for example ü in German. I have the Compose key mapped to Right Alt, and it does not work in this layout. It works in English (US) layout, however.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov: That conflict can be dealt with in *Settings -> Keyboard -> Special Character Entry*. Please make up your mind about which layout you want to use. Otherwise it's hard to guide you further.

Comment: I did not quite understand. I have set the Compose key to the Right Alt key. However, in "English (UK, Macintosh)" keyboard layout, it stops working. So, it looks to me more like a bug than something that I did not set correctly.

Comment: I would prefer to use English US keyboard layout but I need to put ` and ~ on the key between the Left Shift and Z keys.

Comment: I actually tried a similar (to the one you suggested) solution via `xmodmap` and it worked for me: adding `~/.Xmodmap` with the line `keycode 94 = grave asciitilde` and then in the terminal `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DmitryKabanov: Great! Would be good if you could submit an answer with that solution. Just a control question: It only works on X and not Wayland, right?

Comment: @DmitryKabanov: As regards the compose key, you may have hit [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1969396).

Comment: Yes, it looks like this from the commands. I've never used Wayland so far.

Comment: thank you for the link to the bug. Apparently, this is exactly the bug that I have encountered, as the English (UK, Macintosh) is the second layout in the list, and the Rigth Alt works as an Alternative Symbols, although unset. However, now I am quite happy with English (US) layout, after I remapped the key between Left Shift and Z.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me via `xmodmap`.

1. Execute `xev` in the terminal and press the key between Left Shift and Z keys. In the terminal will appear the information about the keycode, which is required for the next step. For me, the keycode is 94.
2. Add file `~/.Xmodmap` with the line

   ```
   keycode 94 = grave asciitilde
   ```
3. Execute in the terminal

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```